# Using Bootstrap with isomorphic reactjs

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, fluxible

I m actually developping some little component with fluxible to understand a bit more isomorphic javascript and react components.

However, I was wondering how can I use the standard twitter bootstrap on this kind of isomorphic app ?

I dont really want to use a CDN in a first place, just to understand what is the manipulation I should do. But I dont know how to reference both on the client and the server side.

Comment: You’ll find it cumbersome to use the standard bootstrap javascript library on React components, since React uses a DOM diffing algorithm that won’t play well with boostraps DOM manipulations. Try searching for React-friendly variants instead.

Comment: Did you try googling "react bootstrap"?